# How do I calculate the width of a bounding rectangle, for text wrapped to fit certain ratio?

Tags: algorithm, text

If I have the following text:

"Hello this is a piece of text that will be displayed in a rectangle area of the screen"

I know the total width of the text.

I am trying to find a bounding width to wrap the text at, based on a given ratio.

What is the algorithm?

For example, I want to always try and wrap the text by width and height where the bounding rectangle has a ratio of 16:9. This needs to happen for whatever length text is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's how i would do it in pseudocode

```
function calcWidth(string text, int rows, float ratio)

    let H be int with value /* how many pixels high is a row? */
    let total_width be int with value 0
    for each character c in string text
        let total_width be total_width + pixel_width(c)
    end for

    let W = total_width / length(text)

    /* RATIO = (H * row) / (W * col) */
    /* means col = (H * row) / (W * RATIO) */

    let cols be int with value (H * rows) / (W * ratio)

    return cols
end function
```

I might also put a check in there that if 5 rows was unacceptable, but 6 rows was worse, that I know 5 is better than 6 so i would return 5 in that case.

Let's review what we know

For a monospaced font:

```
    H * rows
   ---------- = RATIO
    W * cols
```

Now, we know cols won't be the same for each row because we might not have monospaced. However, we can approximate cols as the total number of letters divided by the number of rows.

```
        H * rows
    -------------- = RATIO
    W * len / rows

      H * rows^2
    -------------- = RATIO
       W * len
```

Now you know all of these variables except rows, so solve for rows

```
   rows = roundUp ( SQRT (  (RATIO * W * len) / h ) )
```

Now we know from above that cols is approximately

```
   cols = (H * rows) / (W * ratio)
```

With these two you should have a decent guess for your box.

You might have to render it to see, and maybe go up or down a extra row or two, depending on the size and margin of error.

Comment: I need to find the calculation without rows or height; Only aspect ratio. I am trying to calculate the best guess width for the bounding rectangle, which I then pass onto another function that wraps the text word by word and calculates the height.

Comment: @skn3 revamped to meet those requests.

Answer (score 0):

Since word length is unpredictable, I think there's no better approach than generate-and-test. You can start by finding a word boundary that is, say, 9/16-th the way into the text and using the width up to that point as the candidate width. Then iterative wrap all the text, measure the result, and move the first boundary one word left or right until you get as close as possible. That gives you an optimal break for the first line and upper and lower bounds (one word more or one word less) within which you can, if you like, search further for an optimal solution using, perhaps, binary search.

Comment: I was trying to avoid iterating over word wrap due to the real-time nature of the calculation. I am not *as* concerned about the word length because I can forsee that chopped words won't happen too much. Any ideas for a method to guestimate that doesn't involve large iteration loops?